# Google Assistant opens music settings instead of spotify

Tags: spotify, google-assistant

I'm trying to set up my Google Assistant to play some Spotify music. I've linked Spotify in the settings, and when I say a command like 'OK Google, Play Some Music' it responds 'OK, Playing music on Spotify', but it won't actually start Spotify app, it just opens the Music settings.

It does display a link to open Spotify app if I manually select it, but surely it should open Spotify itself?

[image]

You can see it recognises my command. But then it opens this Settings screen instead:
[image]

Incidentally, I can just ask it to 'OK Google, open Spotify' and it will open it that way, but it won't if I ask it to play any music.

Is there a setting somewhere that I'm missing?

This is on an S8+ so it's pretty up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly have a proper solution to this, but I had the same exact problem. And it was fixed by restarting my phone (Pixel). So that might be worth a try.

Comment: Well what do you know - that sorted it. Now I feel like an idiot for not trying the most obvious solution first - turn it off and turn it back on again!